# Use separate cs file WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I know a little bit in C# with Winforms, but I am currently working with WPF for the first time.

There's the problem : I created a class file named ConnectDB.cs, who contains a class named ConnectDB with a few methods in it, used to connect to a Database.

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs I need to appeal this class, but it doesn't work ! The compiler says "The name 'ConnectDB' does not exist in the current context". But when I add my ConnectDB class directly in the MainWindow.cs it runs smoothly !

So, basically, my question is : how to use a class from another cs file in WPF ?

(I already tested the same thing with Winforms and it works, so I'm a little bit lost)

Comment: Namespaces of both classes are same?

Comment: Have you declared a using for the namespace of the class in your mainwindow?

Comment: theck the name space and the class is it public ?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using, that way we may be able to see what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can not call your class then I think about that :

1* Check if you have the same namespaces

2* Check if your class is public

3* if all Ok then try to Clean and rebuild your solution

Comment: Indeed, the namespaces weren't the same. Shame on me ! Thank you !